# how to query a sql table using angular js and node js

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js

I want to create a form with inputs as employee id and to and from date and query my sql table based on EmployeeID and to and from date filters . Depending on the input of employee id and to and from date my sql table should return and show data.I am using node.js for server side . I want to know how will i pass data from html form to controller and from controller to node to query sql table and get desired output .Here is my attendance.html file

```
<h2>Please select a file in .xlsx format to upload</h2>

<form action="ProcessAttendanceAPI" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="attendanceFile" type="file" class="form-control">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Upload File</button>
</form>
<br>
<h4>{{title}}</h4>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" ng-click="showAlert()">
    Generate Report</button>
<div class="container" ng-show="myvalue">

    <h3>SEARCH BY</h3>
    <select class="form-control" ng-model='SearchTerm'>
        <option value='$'>PLEASE CHOOSE ONE OPTION</option>
        <option value='employeeId'>EMPLOYEE ID</option>
        <option value='punch_date'>DATE</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <div class="container">
        <h5>Search Key:
            <h5>
                <br>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchKeyword[SearchTerm]">
    </div>
    <br>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Employee ID</td>
                <td>DATE</td>
                <td>IN TIME</td>
                <td>OUT TIME</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="blog in blogs | filter:searchKeyword">
                <td>{{blog.employeeId}}</td>
                <td>{{blog.punch_date}}</td>
                <td>a {{blog.min}}</td>
                <td>{{blog.max}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

My SQL TABLE STRUCTURE IS

```
CREATE TABLE `emp_attendance` (

`attendance_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`punch_date` date not null,
`punch_in_timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
`punch_out_timestamp` datetime,
`employeeId` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
`upload_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`attendance_id`),
-- KEY `FK_emp_attendance_1` (`employeeId`),
KEY `FK_emp_attendance_2` (`upload_id`),
-- CONSTRAINT `FK_emp_attendance_1` FOREIGN KEY (`employeeId`) REFERENCES `employee` (`employeeId`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_emp_attendance_2` FOREIGN KEY (`upload_id`) REFERENCES `emp_attendance_uploads` (`upload_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=59 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As of now i am getting the entire data stored in sql table from the following code in node.js

```
exports.Attendancedata = function(req, res) {

    dbconfig.getConnection(function(err, con) {
        con.query('SELECT employeeId as employeeId, punch_date as punch_date,min(punch_in_timestamp) as min ,max(punch_out_timestamp) as max FROM emp_attendance group by employeeId, punch_date',
            function(err, results) {
                if (err) {
                    handleError(err, res);
                } else {
                    res.send(results);
                }
            });
        con.release();
    });
}
```